# How to display a number with dot at third and next third and next fourth digit for a 10 digit number?

Tags: java, android, string, android-activity

I tried this code but it splits based on country code.

```
String phone ="1234567891";
String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phone);
```

but this displays as 123-456-7891

I want to displayed like this:

```
123.456.7891
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I also new to this. So can you explain what is nature of this number??

Comment: @PankajKumar i done changes.

Comment: a fugly solution would be `String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phone).replaceAll("-", "\\.");`

Comment: thanks all..i couldn't give vote up reputation to few answers too. however thanks for solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
    String phoneNum = "1234567891";
    System.out.println(phoneNum.replaceFirst("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "$1.$2.$3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the count of the digits then you can insert the dots at certain positions:

```
String str = "12345678910";
str = str.substring(0, 3) + "." + str.substring(3, 6) + "." + 
    str.substring(6, x.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string replace:

```
String phone ="1234567891";
String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phone);
String formattedNumberWithDots = formattedNumber.replaceAll("-", ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

For string operations(like concatenation) it is always better to use StringBuilder or StringBuffer.

```
   String str = "1234567890";
    if (str.matches("\\d{10}")) {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(str);
        strBuilder.insert(3, ".");
        strBuilder.insert(7, ".");
        System.out.println(strBuilder.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println( str + " is not a phone number");
    }
```